# ubuntu 14.04 - unable to remove ppa:ondrej/php5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ubuntu-14.04

Can anyone please help me to remove broken package ondrej/php5-5.6 , I am trying to install Ruby on Rails , but when I run `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` command , it throws -

```
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

I searched it's solution and found "404 errors should be fixed for rvm to proceed" then I run `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`
to fix broken package but

`getting Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ondrej/+archive/php5-5.6) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.`

I have checked internet connection and it is proper.
[image]

Thank much!!!

Comment: Am afraid, _it is not a programming question_, try in superuser.com

Comment: @Inian , thanks much for your suggestion , I'll post it there too but it is related with ruby on rails installation so I though may be I can get proper solution.

Comment: But it does not involving any code to solve this (not sure) just a bunch of installation commands.

Comment: may be somebody else has already faced this issue while installing ruby on rails , so they might help me.

Comment: I am following this link to install - http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, @inian is perfectly right that installation questions don’t belong here. This particular question highlights a specific Ubuntu problem, so it belongs to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). However, if you reword it as *is there a non-standard way to remove a ppa, when `add-apt-repository` doesn’t work for some reason?* it is possible to answer it here (I think) with a bash script:

```
for ppa in $(fgrep -l ondrej /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*); do 
  mv -i "$ppa" "${ppa}.disabled";
done;
apt-get update
```

(I put semicolons in so that you can run it as a one-liner without having to add them, if you like)

Also, you mention Ubuntu-14.04 as a tag, but the ppa you are trying to remove is for Ubuntu-12.04 (precise). This might explain the errors.

Comment: Thank you so much , it is working now!! sorry for choosing wrong platform to ask this question , after Inian suggestion I have also posted it at http://superuser.com/questions/1170884/ubuntu-14-04-unable-to-remove-ppaondrej-php5 , thanks a lot both of you and Inian